# What is the regex for decimals with or without leading zeros, and not one trailing zero?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have this regex (for up to 3 numbers after the decimal):

```
/^(\d*[1-9]\d*(\.\d{1,3})?|0*\.\d{1,3})$/
```

I'm hoping to set these as **valid**:

- 0
- 0.01
- 0.1
- 12
- 12.01
- 12.1
- 12.420

And these as **invalid**:

- 12.0
- 0.0
- 012

Comment: What about 012?

Comment: @brso05 invalid

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems to do the trick

```
^(0|[1-9]\d*)(\.\d{0,2}[1-9])?$
```

https://regex101.com/r/6ZKH3f/1/

To only disallow `.0` and accept e.g. `.120`,

```
^(0|[1-9]\d*)(\.(?!0$)\d{1,3})?$
```

Comment: actually then 12.420 becomes invalid. how would i account for that?

Comment: @bentedder thought you didn't want any trailing 0's...?

Comment: Yeah I'm an idiot. That second answer works great though! Thanks